# Puppet print all attributes of a resource

Tags: ruby, puppet, puppet-enterprise

In the exists? method I get the value from a remote source. Then I want to check the value against what has been requested. My resource type is volume

```
volume { 'create a volume 1':
  ensure      => present,
  name        => "vol1",
  description => 'This is a volume',
  size        => '100g',
  snap_reserve => 10,
  force       => true,
  transport   => hiera('credentials')
}
```

In my exist? method

```
def exists?
  $token=getAuthToken(resource[:transport])
  allVolumes = returnAllVolumes(resource[:transport])
  allVolumes.each do |volume|
      if resource[:name].eql? volume["name"]
         # Here I want to compare the value from resource
         return true
      end
  end
  return false      
end
```

How do I print all attributes ? In this case "name,description,size,snap_reserve"

Comment: Are you aware of this https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/lvm

Comment: Volume is my own provider. I am not using the lvm as pointed by the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash(resource) is what I was looking for.